# Method not found: 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.get_InClientBuildManager'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, razor, mono

I'm running ASP.NET MVC 4 application on Linux machine thanks to Mono, my problem is that each time I run it for few seconds instead of displaying page I get following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.get_InClientBuildManager'.
```

Description:

```
HTTP 500.Error processing request.
```

Details:

```
Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
```

Exception stack trace:

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Version Information(server is xsp):

```
3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

Detailed info:

```
[System.Web.HttpException]: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartMethods () [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in :0 [System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartMethods () [0x00000] in :0 [System.MissingMethodException]: Method not found: 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.get_InClientBuildManager'. at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
```

As I said, this error is gone shortly after starting application but I'm looking for solution to it. I don't have similiar error on other machine.

Version information(Debian+Nginx+FastCGI):

```
3.6.1 (master/1910095 Mon Jul 7 12:30:38 CEST 2014); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

Comment: hey, I'm currently facing the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. At the end it is a very minor issue and has low impact on application.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16474